# Kernel BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, ram

So I'm trying to run [this kernel module](https://github.com/derekmolloy/exploringBB/tree/master/extras/kernel/ebbchar) on my laptop, and every time I do so, I get a stack trace that looks like this (all the messages might not be relevant to the module).

```
[17539.035247] EBBChar: Device has been opened 1 time(s)
[17540.764549] RTW: traffic_status_watchdog(wlo1) acqiure wake_lock for 4500 ms(tx:17,rx_unicast:12)
[17540.764568] RTW: rtw_set_ps_mode(wlo1) Leave 802.11 power save - WIFI-TRAFFIC_BUSY
[17540.764579] RTW: rtl8723d_set_FwPwrMode_cmd(): FW LPS mode = 0, SmartPS=2
[17540.806242] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007ffcf8935290
[17540.806259] PGD 800000023ba1b067 P4D 800000023ba1b067 PUD 23ba14067 PMD 1ee43e067 PTE 80000001f1986067
[17540.806294] Oops: 0001 [#4] PREEMPT SMP PTI
[17540.806311] CPU: 2 PID: 26810 Comm: test Tainted: G      D    OE     4.18.16-arch1-1-ARCH #1
[17540.806321] Hardware name: HP HP Laptop 15-bs0xx/8329, BIOS F.40 05/16/2018
[17540.806341] RIP: 0010:string+0x20/0x80
[17540.806348] Code: 86 61 00 00 4c 01 e3 eb 81 90 49 89 f2 48 89 ce 48 c1 fe 30 4c 8d 46 ff 48 81 fa ff 0f 00 00 76 46 48 85 f6 74 54 48 8d 42 01 <0f> b6 12 84 d2 74 49 41 b9 01 00 00 00 49 01 c0 41 29 c1 eb 0c 48 
[17540.806538] RSP: 0018:ffffb2fa4546bd88 EFLAGS: 00010286
[17540.806548] RAX: 00007ffcf8935291 RBX: ffffffffc16644a0 RCX: ffff0a00ffffff04
[17540.806556] RDX: 00007ffcf8935290 RSI: ffffffffffffffff RDI: ffffffffc16644a0
[17540.806563] RBP: ffffffffffffffff R08: fffffffffffffffe R09: 0000000000000001
[17540.806570] R10: ffffffffffffffff R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffb2fa4546bde8
[17540.806577] R13: ffffffffc16632d4 R14: 000000003e99bb5f R15: ffffffffc16632d4
[17540.806587] FS:  00007f92e4fb4540(0000) GS:ffffa3a53ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[17540.806595] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[17540.806602] CR2: 00007ffcf8935290 CR3: 00000001df490005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[17540.806609] Call Trace:
[17540.806626]  vsnprintf+0x138/0x4d0
[17540.806647]  sprintf+0x56/0x70
[17540.806663]  ? n_tty_open+0xa0/0xa0
[17540.806678]  dev_write+0x22/0x50 [ebbchar]
[17540.806694]  __vfs_write+0x36/0x190
[17540.806708]  ? __audit_syscall_entry+0xd7/0x160
[17540.806722]  ? syscall_slow_exit_work+0x19b/0x1b0
[17540.806736]  vfs_write+0xa9/0x190
[17540.806751]  ksys_write+0x4f/0xb0
[17540.806764]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x170
[17540.806780]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[17540.806790] RIP: 0033:0x7f92e4edb818
[17540.806795] Code: 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8d 05 25 6d 0d 00 8b 00 85 c0 75 17 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 58 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 41 54 49 89 d4 55 
[17540.806935] RSP: 002b:00007ffcf8935278 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[17540.806946] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f92e4edb818
[17540.806953] RDX: 0000000000000004 RSI: 00007ffcf8935290 RDI: 0000000000000003
[17540.806960] RBP: 00007ffcf89353a0 R08: 00007ffcf8935290 R09: 00007ffcf8934d70
[17540.806967] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000556d07ed70e0
[17540.806975] R13: 00007ffcf8935480 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[17540.806986] Modules linked in: ebbchar(OE) uinput rfcomm fuse cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat snd_hda_codec_hdmi btusb btrtl btbcm uvcvideo btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev ecdh_generic media snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic joydev mousedev snd_soc_skl intel_rapl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_ext_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm snd_hda_intel wmi_bmof crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec hp_wmi crc32_pclmul i915 ghash_clmulni_intel intel_wmi_thunderbolt iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support pcbc snd_hda_core 8723de(OE) aesni_intel aes_x86_64 snd_hwdep snd_pcm crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_timer snd radeon psmouse
[17540.807185]  soundcore intel_cstate intel_uncore input_leds intel_rapl_perf cfg80211 kxcjk_1013 r8169 rfkill evdev pcspkr mii led_class mei_me mei wmi battery intel_gtt ac industrialio_triggered_buffer intel_vbtn kfifo_buf sparse_keymap mac_hid hp_wireless processor_thermal_device int340x_thermal_zone intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel intel_pch_thermal industrialio i2c_i801 pcc_cpufreq vboxnetflt(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxpci(OE) vboxdrv(OE) sg crypto_user ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 fscrypto sr_mod cdrom sd_mod ahci libahci serio_raw atkbd libps2 libata crc32c_intel scsi_mod i8042 serio amdgpu chash i2c_algo_bit gpu_sched drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ttm drm agpgart [last unloaded: ebbchar]
[17540.807360] CR2: 00007ffcf8935290
[17540.807371] ---[ end trace 75129f1c4beeb924 ]---
[17540.807383] RIP: 0010:strcpy+0x5/0x20
[17540.807388] Code: 8d 47 08 3a 0f 75 f4 48 83 c7 01 48 39 c7 75 f3 31 c0 eb 99 48 85 c0 74 b2 c3 48 89 f8 e9 68 ff ff ff 0f 1f 00 48 89 f8 31 d2 <0f> b6 0c 16 88 0c 10 48 83 c2 01 84 c9 75 f1 c3 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 
[17540.807528] RSP: 0018:ffffb2fa4517be40 EFLAGS: 00010246
[17540.807538] RAX: ffffffffc16684e0 RBX: 00007ffe4e75be50 RCX: ffffb2fa4517bf08
[17540.807545] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007ffe4e75be50 RDI: ffffffffc16684e0
[17540.807552] RBP: ffffb2fa4517bf08 R08: ffffa3a51b37a700 R09: 0000000000000001
[17540.807559] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
[17540.807566] R13: ffffb2fa4517bf08 R14: 00007ffe4e75be50 R15: 0000000000000000
[17540.807575] FS:  00007f92e4fb4540(0000) GS:ffffa3a53ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[17540.807583] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[17540.807590] CR2: 00007ffcf8935290 CR3: 00000001df490005 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[17540.808298] EBBChar: Device successfully closed
```

It works on my friend's desktop, so I assumed it was something specific to my distribution. I used a different distro (arch to mint) and found the same stack trace. Then I thought might be something with either my RAM or hard drive. I tried to boot from a live linux USB and compile and run it there, and it didn't run, so it must have been my RAM

Finally I ran memtest86 and came back with zero errors or warnings. So I'm completely baffled as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Please put that trace in the question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Not sure what happened to the link, but I've updated my post

Comment: The module is buggy because it does not check for overflowing the internal `message` buffer, which has a hardcoded size of 256 bytes. The crash happens in the write function.